# MySql get the sum of a column in every rows of a new column

Tags: mysql

I have the following data set:

```
market sale
fr       10
uk       10
fr       12
fr        3
uk        1
```

and I want to add a new column where i can display the sum of sale in every row of the new column like this

```
market sale total sale 
fr       10         38 
uk       10         38 
us        3         38
fr        2         38
fr       12         38
uk        1         38
```

mu query need to be in Mysql

thanks

Comment: How is `total sale` calculated?

Comment: `total sale` column doesn't make much sense as it has the same value(the sum of all `sale` column values). It's wrong design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You request select id wrong designed  but  if you really need

You can calculate the sum in column using a subselect

```
SELECT  market, sale, (select sum(sale) as total from my_table) as  total
from my_table
```

if you need  only some country  eg FR, UK  you can

```
SELECT  market, sale, (select sum(sale) as total 
                           from my_table
                           where market in ('FR', 'UK')) as  total
from my_table 
here market in ('FR', 'UK')
```

or you need always the total sum  you can

```
SELECT  market, sale, (select sum(sale) as total 
                           from my_table
                          ) as  total
from my_table 
here market in ('FR', UK')
```

Comment: How do I do if I also want to add a where case for exemple where market like FR and UK.

Comment: and you in this case want only the total sum of these two countries ?

Comment: Thanks that's perfect