# Making a new column from the sum of columns from few rows - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've made select query which populates the following output -

[image]

If we see at the rows above we can see 3 sections here (separated by the dashed line). Each row is unique by 3 attributes (`dpt`, `qn` and `option_choice.id`) If we look at the `votes` column for each section we can see -

> **section 1:**  (3+62+1)=66
>   **section 2:**  (9+1+28+25)=63
>   **section 3:**  (20+29+1+2+8)=60

That means questions 1,2 and 3 got 66, 63 and 60 votes respectively. I want to add a 5th column say  `total_votes` just right after the `votes`  which will represent the total votes of each group like this -
[image]

I've already tried with [the cumulative sum technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910760/mysql-get-the-sum-of-a-column-in-every-rows-of-a-new-column) Can anyone help how can I do this?
Here is my working query (that produced the result of the first image) -

```
SELECT s.current_department_code as dpt
     , q.sn
     , oc.text option_choice
     , COUNT(jqooc.question_option_id) votes_per_option
FROM answers a
     , surveyors s
     , question_options qo
     , questions q
     , jt_question_options_option_choices jqooc 
     , option_choices oc
 WHERE a.surveyor_id = s.id
  AND a.question_option_id = qo.id
  AND qo.question_id = q.id
  AND qo.id = jqooc.question_option_id
  AND jqooc.option_choice_id = oc.id
GROUP  
    BY
    dpt
     , q.sn
     , jqooc.option_choice_id
     , option_choice
ORDER 
    BY  dpt ASC
     , q.sn ASC
     , option_choice ASC;
```

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Look for `GROUP BY .. WITH ROLLUP` also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
SELECT s.current_department_code as dpt, q.sn, oc.text option_choice,
       COUNT(*) as votes_per_option,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY s.current_department_code, q.sn) as question_total
```

I'm not going to touch the rest of the query.  Suffice it to say that you should be using proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.